# Swift expected type Array<_>

Tags: ios, swift, generics, reactive-cocoa, reactive-cocoa-3

I'm trying to write a UITableView RAC3 Binding helper in swift 2.

I'm trying to initialize my binding helper which has a signature `init(tableView: UITableView, sourceSignal: SignalProducer<[T], NoError>, reuseIdentifier: String, selectionCommand: (() -> Void)? = nil)`

My code is `self.bindingHelper = TableViewBindingHelper<PostCellViewModel>(tableView: tableView, sourceSignal: viewModel.posts.producer, reuseIdentifier: R.reuseIdentifier.contactReuseIdentifier.identifier)`

I get a compiler error on the `sourceSignal: viewModel.posts.producer`, saying that `Cannot convert value of type 'SignalProducer<[PostCellViewModel], NoError>' (aka 'SignalProducer<Array<PostCellViewModel>, NoError>') to expected argument type 'SignalProducer<[_], NoError>' (aka 'SignalProducer<Array<_>, NoError>')`, which makes no sense to...

It's saying that it's expecting a `SignalProducer<[_], NoError>`. I assumed the _ means it doesn't care what type I pass in, but then I try to pass in an array of `PostCellViewModel` it fails?

Comment: Could you add the types for all the variables you are using? What type is `viewModel.posts.producer`?

Comment: viewModel.posts.producer  is a SignalProducer<[PostCellViewModel], NoError>.

Comment: I also added a demo project https://github.com/AndrewSB/reactive-table-view

Comment: did you find a solution? I'm stuck in the same issue.

Comment: Yeah, I changed the method signature. Here's an example of a correct invocation: https://github.com/AndrewSB/reactive-table-view/blob/master/reactive%20table%20view/InitialViewController.swift#L18